# Replace None value by list in an np array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to replace a None value in a numpy array with a list of one element inside an np array :

```
data_inputs = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [None], None])
data_inputs = np.where(array == None, [5], data_inputs)
```

I get the following results :

```
   np.array([[1], [2], [3], [5], 5])
```

I want to following results :

```
   np.array([[1], [2], [3], [5], [5]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [132]: x = np.array([[1], [2], [3], None])
```

replacing the element by simple index works:

```
In [133]: x[3]=[5]                                                              
In [134]: x                                                                     
Out[134]: array([list([1]), list([2]), list([3]), list([5])], dtype=object)
```

Finding the `None` element:

```
In [135]: x = np.array([[1], [2], [3], None])                                   
In [136]: x==None                                                               
Out[136]: array([False, False, False,  True])
```

Often we say use `is None` instead, but that doesn't work with arrays.  Here I suspect object array test may be doing an id match.  So this test is tentative.

We can use the boolean mask to find the `x`:

```
In [137]: x[x==None]                                                            
Out[137]: array([None], dtype=object)
In [138]: x[x==None]=[5]                                                        
In [139]: x                                                                     
Out[139]: array([list([1]), list([2]), list([3]), 5], dtype=object)
```

But this put the number not the list; I suspect this is because `Out[137]` is returning a 1d array.

Your `where` is probably close to this use of `np.nonzero` (alias `np.where`):

```
In [142]: x = np.array([[1], [2], [3], None])                                   
In [143]: idx = np.nonzero(x==None)                                             
In [144]: idx                                                                   
Out[144]: (array([3]),)
In [145]: x[idx]                                                                
Out[145]: array([None], dtype=object)
```

If we extract the scalar index from `idx`, it does work:

```
In [146]: x[idx[0][0]]                                                          
In [147]: x[idx[0][0]] = [5]                                                    
In [148]: x                                                                     
Out[148]: array([list([1]), list([2]), list([3]), list([5])], dtype=object)
```

So I can replace a single element of the object array with a list provided I use a scalar index, not a list, boolean, or array index.  I'm not sure what we should do if the example had several `None`.

In sum, there are 2 issues

- reliably identifying the `None`
- replacing an element of an object array with a list.

The alternative of working with a list comprehension is worth considering. Speed will be comprable, if not better, than array methods.  Object dtype arrays are inherently slower than numeric ones.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code you provided doesn't run, so I'm assuming you meant

```
data_inputs = np.array([[1], [2], [3], None])
```

According to [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), numpy.where is not different from a list comprehension when all arrays are 1D.

This means you can solve this with

```
np.array([ [5] if d is None else d for d in data_inputs ])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the following slightly esoteric trick: Wrap the list in a 0D array.

```
data_inputs = np.array([[1], [2], [3], None])
# create 0D object array
# can't do np.array([5],object) for obvious reasons, instead
aux = np.array(None)
aux[()] = [5]

# and now
np.where(data_inputs == None, aux, data_inputs)
# array([list([1]), list([2]), list([3]), list([5])], dtype=object)
```